# Mixed languages link error with meson build system (Fortran/C++)

Tags: c++, fortran, hpc, intel-fortran, meson-build

I am encountering issues when trying to compile fortran code using meson build system on an HPC cluster.

On the cluster, I am using Intel compiler suite. The `meson compile` command aborts at the linking step with:

```
ld: /usr/bin/../lib64/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The interesting thing is that the link command issued by meson is something like this:
`icpc  -o main main.p/somefile.o ...`, so it is using Intel's C++ compiler to link my fortran code. I tried to use the exact same command line, replacing *icpc* with *ifort* and adding `-lstdc++`. That actually worked.

So, I wonder, is there a way to force Meson to link my code with `ifort`, instead of `icpc`? Or, should I do something else?

I am afrad I cannot share the code at this moment. But, I'm open to showing bits and pieces of the meson.build file(s), if needed.

#### Details

- The codebase consists of fortran source and a CMake C++ subproject; Essentially, the C++ subproject is a wrapper for OpenCV image plotting functions. This is why I needed to add `-lstdc++` to my successful manual link command above.
- Meson version: 0.55.3
- Intel Fortran compiler: ifort (IFORT) 19.1.3.304 20200925
- Intel C++ compiler: icpc (ICC) 19.1.3.304 20200925
- The code is MPI parallelised.
- The same code compiles well with GNU compilers v10 on a normal workstation.

Comment: I think I'll try with `link_language` and `add_global_link_arguments`. Still, this all looks a bit ... like did I move from autotools for this? :)

Comment: So, if I use `link_language : fortran` in the `executable` call and `fortran_link_args` in the native file, I think I override all the other link flags (including dependencies). This seems to be a dead end. Using `add_global_link_arguments` with `-lstdc++` causes other errors...

Comment: Investigating this further, it seems Intel compilers have arguments such as `-cxxlib` and `-nofor_main` to enable linking objects from multiple languages together. This should be the equivalent of linking with `-lstdc++`, or `-lgfortran` with GCC. I wonder how you do that in the case of `clang` and `flang`.

Answer (score 2):

Meson is not going to do any hand-holding when it comes to mixing languages. Here is what I found out works for Intel compilers:

```
fc=meson.get_compiler('fortran')
# cxx=meson.get_compiler('cpp')
...
if (fc.get_id() == 'intel')
#if (cxx.get_id() == 'intel')
...
add_global_link_arguments('-cxxlib',language : 'fortran')
add_global_link_arguments('-nofor_main', language : 'cpp')
endif

...

executable('myprog','myprog.f90', ..., link_language : 'fortran')
#executable('myprog','myprog.f90',...)
```

Comment: Meson docs would suggest using `add_project_link_arguments` instead of `add_global_link_arguments`.

Comment: Da, ima smisla...